# detecting location by wifi/mobile networks

Tags: android, gps, location

I have this code for detecting location:

```
public class LocationDetector implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private Location lastloc;
    private Context _context;

    public LocationDetector(Context context){
        _context = context;
    }

    public Location getlastloc(){
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        return location;
    }

    public void start(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lastloc = getlastloc();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
    }

    public void stop(){
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("states", "onLocationChanged()");
        lastloc = location;
        Log.d("states", "lat: "+lastloc.getLatitude()+"lat: "+lastloc.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

the problem is that onLocationChanged() fires only if gps option is enabled on phone and if only wifi/mobile networks option is enabled onLocationChanged() don't fire and don't detect location.

even if I connected to internet and wifi/mobile networks option is enabled don't detect location again.

so this option is for what ? and when does it work ?

Comment: I think you might be setting your request for updates to be too large.  Try using a smaller value than 400.

Comment: I changed it to 0 now and still don't give me location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
```

First you are requesting to get the updates from Network provider and again you are requesting to get the updates from GPS provider. Because of this you will get the updates only from GPS provider. You need to add the following condition to meet your requirement.

```
//if condition to check if GPS is available  
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) { 
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
                    }  
       else if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {  
                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your mannifest file for which permissions are required.
According to the documentation, when using both gps and network provider, you should define access_fine_location, which includes permissions for both.

Have a look on your criteria, when setting empty criteria you would not get any updates.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html

Comment: I used criteria in getlastloc() method that is an optional method and I can don't use it. my problem there is I can't get any location by wifi/mobile networks.